# Number of records returned from full outer join increases as more join criteria is added

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, full-outer-join

I'm full outer joining two tables. Table 1 (LEAD) has 689,189 rows and table 2 (CONTACT) has 133,318 rows, and a full outer join on them returns 738,959 rows. So far this makes sense.

Each table has a field that indicates whether the record is logically deleted, with a `Y` value meaning it is. I only want to return rows in both tables that have a value not equal to `Y`. When I add the additional criteria to the query

```
select COUNT(*)
from LEAD l
full join CONTACT c on l.CONVERTEDCONTACTID = c.ID and l.DELETE_FLAG <> 'Y' and c.DELETE_FLAG <> 'Y'
```

I get more rows returned than without them. Shouldn't they make the query more restrictive? I know I can perform the join using subqueries but I'm just not understanding how I'm arriving at this result.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: put the new criteria in the where clause instead.

```
select COUNT(*)
from LEAD l
full join CONTACT c on l.CONVERTEDCONTACTID = c.ID
where l.DELETE_FLAG <> 'Y' and c.DELETE_FLAG <> 'Y'
```

The extra join conditions are adding more records with nulls from the table on the other side of the join, leading to extra results.

I'm not 100% sure on how a full join with a condition that only effects one side is handled; `l.DELETE_FLAG <> 'Y'` and `c.DELETE_FLAG <> 'Y'` each only look at one of the two tables in the join, and I'm reasonably certain that is the cause.

Comment: Placing the conditions in the where clause won't give me what I'm looking for– it will turn the full join into an inner by removing all of the rows that have null delete flags on either side.

Comment: Then change `l.DELETE_FLAG <> 'Y'` to `(l.DELETE_FLAG is null or l.DELETE_FLAG <> 'Y')` (or to `coalesce(l.DELETE_FLAG, 'N') <> 'Y'`), but keep it in the where clause.

Answer (score 0):

Just put the additional criteria in WHERE clause, like following:

```
select COUNT(*)
    from LEAD l
    full join CONTACT c on l.CONVERTEDCONTACTID = c.ID 
    where  l.DELETE_FLAG <> 'Y' and c.DELETE_FLAG <> 'Y'
```

If your tables contain NULL values, then tune it like following:

```
select COUNT(*) 
     from LEAD l 
     full join CONTACT c on l.CONVERTEDCONTACTID = c.ID 
     where  (l.DELETE_FLAG <> 'Y' or l.DELETE_FLAG is NULL) and 
     (c.DELETE_FLAG <> 'Y' or c.DELETE_FLAG is NULL)
```